# APN (Grocer Gem) sslv3 alert certificate unknown error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, push-notification, ssl-certificate

When I send a message I get this error in the sidekiq console,

SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A: sslv3 alert certificate unknown

I saw a similar error for people using apn_on_rails and they thought it had something to do with the certificate which someone redid and it worked. I tried doing the same but still get the same error. Any idea what it could be? I am currently using the grocer gem to handle push notifications.

Comment: Making sure you are not trying to connect to the sandbox APNS server with a production certificate or vice versa.

Comment: figured it out, was using the wrong certificate. I now am trying to test to see if the push notification is actually being sent, I've stated the device token of my phone and I'm not getting errors when the code is run but I'm not sure how I can check to see if its being sent.

Comment: Didn't it reach your device? Make sure you are using the production device token (for the sandbox env, your device has a different token).

Comment: For some reason it wasn't working but after restarting sidekiq it began functioning so problem solved, thanks!